# Fourier Series Transformation of Piecewise Function

Tags: fourier-series, differential, piecewise-continuity

I would appreciate some help with the question below. It is just for personal study to get ahead for next year, but the textbook doesn't have answers, and I am unsure how to do b and d specifically. I have done a as it is quite simple, and I have the an and bn general formulas, I just don't know how to use them to solve it.

Question:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkDLc.png

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Write down the integral for $a_n$ as a sum of three disjoint integrals (hint, one of them is immediately 0). Then integrate.